# Filtering ListView & QFileSystemModel Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I've got a strange problem with filtering QFileSystemModel

In "dialog.ui" there is only a QListView.

main.cpp

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Dialog w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

dialog.h

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QFileSystemModel>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
    QFileSystemModel* fileModel;
};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

dialog.cpp

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    fileModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    fileModel->setFilter(QDir::Files);

    ui->listView->setModel(fileModel);

    ui->listView->setRootIndex(fileModel->setRootPath("/"));

    ////////////////////////////////// - Problem!
    fileModel->setRootPath("/home/");
    fileModel->setRootPath("/");
    //////////////////////////////////
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

The problem is I see "home" folder (only this one) on the list, although filtering is set to `QDir::Files`. How to delete this entry?

[image]

Comment: spamming `fileModel->setFilter(QDir::Files);` everywhere doesn't help

Comment: explain yourself better, I do not understand you, besides why do you use 3 times setRootIndex()?

Comment: my fault, it should be `fileModel->setRootPath("/home/");
    fileModel->setRootPath("/");` without these two lines a list contains four files and no folders. With these lines there is also "home" folder, although filtering is set to QDir::Files.

Comment: I do not understand you, correct your code. Also for these cases it is advisable to attach an image of what you get and what you want to obtain.

Comment: @inter22, when you use  `fileModel->setFilter(QDir::Files);` the result will be only files are shown ..

Comment: @inter22, what is your OS? Windows .. Linux ?

Comment: @inter22, you cant set RootPath twice in this way ..

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/YeOHw

Comment: test by setting the filter again.

Comment: setting filters multiple times doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

If you want a file explorer with tree view showing folders and list view showing files, change QListView to QTreeView, Use the following constructor code, which is portable:

```
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    fileModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    fileModel->setFilter(QDir::Files);

    ui->treeView->setModel(fileModel);


    auto myhome = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::HomeLocation);
    ////////////////////////////////// - Problem!
    ui->treeView->setRootIndex(fileModel->setRootPath(myhome));
    ui->treeView->setRootIndex(fileModel->setRootPath("/"));

    //////////////////////////////////
}
```

Comment: @inter22, I tested my code in answer .. its working as expected!

Comment: it works the same as my program without these two lines... I want to write a file explorer with tree view showing folders and list view showing files. Everything works well on the start, but changing directories cause same problem... https://imgur.com/a/A6pmz why is "Obrazy" on the left (code to change directory is basically the same)

Comment: @inter22, thats not possible! `QListview` does not display horizontal or vertical headers; to display a list of items with a horizontal header, use `QTreeView`

Comment: @inter22, I updated the code showing treeview .. its basically similar ,,